# Silex url parameter routing incorrectly

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, routes, silex

I am setting up a site with silex and I am sure this is a n00b question.  I have my htaccess set up (per the silex recommendation) to redirect to my home page if a url does not exist.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

so  /mysite/api/v1/users  will load correctly and display the JSON and list all users, but /mysite/api/v1/somerandomfolder    will redirect to the home page.  that is all working fine.

The problem I am having is when I try /mysite/api/v1/users/00001   (00001 being the user id), it is redirecting me back to the homepage rather than displaying the JSON for the specific user.

my code in index.php inside my users folder looks like this:

```
$users = array(
 '00001'=> array(
     'name' => 'John Doe',
     'age' => '53',
     'description' => '...',
     'image' => 'john.jpg',
 ),
 '00002' => array(
     'name' => 'Jane Doe',
     'age' => '27',
     'description' => '...',
     'image' => 'jane.jpg',
 ),
 );

$app->get('/', function() use ($users) {

 return json_encode($users);
 });

 $app->get('/{userid}', function (Silex\Application $app, $userid) use ($users) {

 if (!isset($users[$userid])) {
     $app->abort(404, "User ID {$userid} does not exist.");
 }
 return json_encode($users[$userid]);
 });

$app->run();
```

I am sure there is some basic concept I am missing but I cannot figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The route is

```
$app->get('/mysite/api/v1/users/{userid}', function (Silex\Application $app, $userid) use ($users) {
}
```

The RewriteBase must be the path to the site root, relative to document root.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work.  it is still doing the same thing and redirecting to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in my Silex app and it seems to work fine.

I think you may be using multiple front controllers (multiple index.php files). This may be possible to accomplish but it goes against the usual [MVC single entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5596774/1814739) concept. Let me know if I'm wrong about the multiple index.php files.